# Radio Box - Can't get it inline

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm not succeeding in getting the radio box and text in the same line, I have no idea why, but can someone help me with an example of how to do this?

```
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 columns">
                                        <label style="max-width: 100px; display: inline; float: left;"><input type="radio" name="main_branch" value="1" style="float: left;">Main Branch</label>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: When you declare a float, the element automatically becomes block-level. The text adjacent to the floated radio input will be rendered inline, so they will not be arranged on the same line.

Comment: In other words, you can't use `float` and `inline` together.

Comment: Reduce font-size, or increase max-width, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float:left;` and you're good:

```html
<div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 columns">
                                        <label style="max-width: 100px; display: inline;"><input type="radio" name="main_branch" value="1" style="float: left;">Main Branch</label>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```